# Toggle switch using html5 and css3

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a hybrid app where I want to show a toggle switch with a[image] customized icon on it. Any idea how to implement this.

Comment: Use bootstrap : http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

Comment: yes bootstrap toggle is really good and easy..

Comment: Please research more before posting like this questions

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery UI... don't tag tags that are not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this simple code

```js
$(".switch").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
});
```

```css
.switch {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.switch > div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #A81414;
    margin-left: 0px;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.switch.on > div {
    margin-left: 50%;
    background: green;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switch">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

See this Fiddle for your requirement.
https://jsfiddle.net/vz9zufk0/

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Toggle.</h1>
<a href="#" class="toggle toggle--on"></a>
<script>
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
  var toggle = this;

  e.preventDefault();

  $(toggle).toggleClass('toggle--on')
         .toggleClass('toggle--off')
         .addClass('toggle--moving');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(toggle).removeClass('toggle--moving');
  }, 200)
});
</script>
```

Comment: You used plugin to do this. Question is about customize switch.

Comment: Yes user can put their icon to customize it...

Answer (score 1):

I use a non Js solution, but be aware Firefox will not be able to display it correctly (a simple checkbox will be displayed though).

```css
input[type="checkbox"].checkboxStyle {
 position: relative;
}

input[type="checkbox"].checkboxStyle,
input[type="checkbox"].checkboxStyle:before {
 width: 77px;
 height: 28px;
}

input[type="checkbox"].checkboxStyle:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 background-image: url('http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/22/1464687124-checkbox.png');
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: background 0.15s ease, color 0.15s ease;
}

input[type="checkbox"].checkboxStyle:not(:checked):before {
 background-position-x: -46px;
}

input[type="checkbox"].checkboxStyle:checked:before {
 background-position-x: 0px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxStyle" />
```